# Remove top padding on bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to remove the padding on the top of the navbar image.

I have tried playing around with the padding numbers and cannot seem to get it.

I can get the padding to be removed but then the positioning of the rest of the elements is moved all around.

```
<style>
    .navbar-inner{
        position:relative;
        padding-left:70px;
    }
    .navbar .brand {                
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 50px;
        background: #f00;        
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #logo{
        height: 40px;
    }

</style>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-top: 0">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img id="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/McZjymS.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Technology Training Calendar</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Flyers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Status Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Procedures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The Upgrade</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tales from Tech Support</a></li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

If I add this to css I can get it to line up but the position is all off

```
#logo{
    height: 40px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell via the browser inspector if your padding is being overridden by later CSS?

Comment: you can try to put the style inline ` style="..."` to make sure it is not overwritten

Comment: Could you post a working code? JSFiddle or a link to the implemenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust by targetting the class holding the image, not the image itself. Like this:

```
       a.navbar-brand {
          padding: 6px 10px; //adjust this accordingly until you have it centered.
       }
```

[**Here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeVYdz) is your code solved

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the padding on the link containing the image with:

```
.navbar-brand {
  padding:0;
}
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/R3EgB5ot3o)**